# Proof of the Laplace transform of the $n$th derivative

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm having trouble formulating a proof of the following theorem:

Let $f$ be a real-valued function having a continuous $(n - 1)$st
derivative $f^{(n - 1)}$ for $t \geq 0$; and assume that $f, f^\prime, f^{\prime\prime}, \dots, f^{(n - 1)}$ are all of exponential order $e^{\alpha t}$. Suppose $f^{(n)}$ is piecewise continuous in every finite closed interval $0 \leq t \leq b$. Then $\mathcal{L} \{ f^{(n)} \}$ exists for $s > \alpha$ and
$$\mathcal{L} \{f^{(n)}\} = s^n\mathcal{L} \{ f \} - s^{n - 1}f(0)-s^{n - 2}f^\prime(0) - s^{n-3} f^{\prime\prime}(0) - \ldots - f^{(n-1)}(0).$$

I think this would be an inductive reasoning proof, but I can't seem to prove the generalization.

I know that
$$\mathcal{L} \{ f^\prime \} = s\mathcal{L} \{ f \} - f(0),$$
and that
$$\mathcal{L} \{ f^{(2)} \} = s^2\mathcal{L} \{ f \} - sf(0)-f^\prime(0)$$
But how should I attempt to generalize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the basis case $n=1$. If $g=f^{(k)}$ and
$$\mathcal{L}(g) = \mathcal{L}(f^{(k)}) = s^k \mathcal{L}(f) - s^{k-1}f(0) - \dotsb - f^{(k-1)}(0), $$
then using the $n=1$ result gives
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(f^{(k+1)})=\mathcal{L}(g') &= s\mathcal{L}(g) - g(0) \\
 &= s(s^k \mathcal{L}(f) - s^{k-1}f(0) - \dotsb - f^{(k-1)}(0)) - f^{(k)}(0) \\
&= s^{k+1} \mathcal{L}(f) - s^{k}f(0) - \dotsb - sf^{(k-1)}(0)) - f^{(k)}(0),
\end{align}
which is of the same form with $k \mapsto k+1$, so combining this with the basis case, induction implies the result holds for all positive integers $n$.