# Proof by induction of Laplace transform property

Tags: calculus, induction, laplace-transform

I am trying to work through the proof of the below theory from Brilliant [1].

$$L(f^{(n)}(t)) = s^n L(f) - \sum_{i=1}^{n} s^{n-i} f^{(i - 1)}(0)$$

and am stuck on the last step. Used integration by parts to show the case is true for n = 1, and to derive for n = k + 1:

$$
L( f^{(k+1)}(t)) = f^{(k)}(0) + sL(f^{(k)}(t))
$$
this is supposed to be equal to the below expression, but I cannot understand how.
$$
s^{k+1}L(f) - \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}s^{k+1-i}f^{(i-1)}(0)
$$
My main problem is trying to get rid of all the terms $s^{k+1-i}f^{(i-1)}(0), i < k + 1$

[1] https://brilliant.org/wiki/laplace-transform/

Comment: This [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291165/proof-of-the-laplace-transform-of-the-nth-derivative?rq=1) addresses your problem.

Comment: Thanks Reza, so just so I have it clear. For some reason I thought they were trying to say these two being equal could be showed by algebraic manipulation. But rather, if we integrate by parts for the case n = k, we get $L(f^{k}(t)) = sL(f^{k-1}(t)) + f^{k-1}(0)$. As we assume this to be true, clearly the case for k + 1 is true, $L(f^{k+1}(t)) = sL(f^{k}(t)) + f^{k}(0)$?

Comment: a related question on notation, at some points in the brilliant article they use the notation $L(f)$, is this just shorthand for  $L(f(t))$?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes. First you should be aware that it is possible to express the Laplace transform of the derivative of a functions in the form of the Laplace transform of the function as there is a well-known relation, using integration by parts. The next step is to use induction. That's the link I mentioned. That's all you need to prove the statement. The answer to your second question is YES. Moreover you can read more about the well-known relation at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2292907/laplace-transformation-of-derivative).